# Exit command in Git Bash for VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

I have an issue with Git Bash integrated terminal in VS Code. When I run a command that results in too many lines, that do not fit screen (eg. `git log`), then it pauses and displays `:` sign. I can continue to next line with Enter key until I reach `(END)` marking.

I don't know how to exit command now and go back to prompt?

Comment: Did you try ':q' or 'q' ?

Comment: Correct, you can post that as an answer!

Comment: in Windows 11, it's `q`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `:q` or `q` to exit and go back to prompt !